# Get Labels Animation Same as Phibrow App

Tags: ios, swift, animation, gestures

I want to create same animation as in [Phibrow App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phiapp/id1022074880?mt=8). Please see following video for more details:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwc69a9ktaa52je/IMG_0155.MOV?dl=0

[image] [image] [image]

I have tried to get this animation using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. But not able to get this animation yet.

```
func handlePinchGesture(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed{
        //print("UIPinchGestureRecognizer")

        gesture.view?.transform = (gesture.view?.transform)!.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y: gesture.scale)
        gesture.scale = 1.0
    }
}


func handleRotationGesture(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed{
        print("UIRotationGestureRecognizer : ", gesture.rotation)
        gesture.view?.transform = (gesture.view?.transform)!.rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
        gesture.rotation = 0
    }
}

func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed{
        //print("UIPanGestureRecognizer")
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        gesture.view?.transform = (gesture.view?.transform)!.translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: view)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get this animation?

Comment: Refer https://www.raywenderlich.com/162745/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 2):

I think this code works for you.
I have declared two views firstView and secondView and added separate gesture for both the views
like if in case of panGesture for example :

```
firstPan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(gesture:)))
    secondPan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(gesture:)))
    firstView.addGestureRecognizer(secondPan!)
    secondView.addGestureRecognizer(firstPan!)
```

for pinch and rotation i have used same method as above to add gesture.
and for your case you need to have pinch and rotation gesture except pan gesture works at a same time for both views so just check which view and apply transform for other view also.

```
@objc func handlePinchGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else { return }
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        if gestureRecognizer.view == firstView {
            gestureRecognizer.view?.transform = (gestureRecognizer.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale))!
            secondView.transform = (secondView.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale))
            gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0
        }else{
            gestureRecognizer.view?.transform = (gestureRecognizer.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale))!
            firstView.transform = (firstView.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale))
            gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0
        }
    }
}


@objc func handleRotationGesture(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed{
        if gesture.view == firstView {
            gesture.view?.transform = (gesture.view?.transform)!.rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
            secondView.transform = (secondView.transform).rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
            gesture.rotation = 0
        }else{
            gesture.view?.transform = (gesture.view?.transform)!.rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
            firstView.transform = (firstView.transform).rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
            gesture.rotation = 0
        }
    }
}

@objc func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed{
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        gesture.view?.transform = (gesture.view?.transform)!.translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: view)
    }
}
```

Comment: @meet-doshi try the above code and let me know if it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that translation is retrieved like `gesture.translation(in: view)`, e.g. in the coordinate system of some `view`. Is the `view` in your example a `gesture.view.superview`? You're interested in how much the `gesture.view` is moved in its `superview` coordinate system, so this condition must be true: `view == gesture.view.superview`.

The second problem is translating of the `transform` - it will not be correct when rotation and/or scale are non-identity. To properly move the `gesture.view`, you should change its `center` position, which will remain correct independently of view rotation or scale:

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    panRecognizer.setTranslation(panRecognizer.view.center, in: panRecognizer.view.superview)
}

func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view.superview)
    gesture.view.center = translation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps problem in order. You are applying translation after applying rotation. On transform that rotated. It means that your destination object will be rotated, and then translated according to ration. So if you rotate object on Float.Pi and try to move object it will move in opposite direction. Instead you had to move object first and then apply existed transform.

```
@IBAction func panRecognised(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began || gesture.state == .changed{
        guard let targetView = gesture.view else { return }
        let transform =  targetView.transform
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        targetView.transform = transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y))
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: view)
    }
}
```